# can't delete a row from post_meta table

Tags: php, database, mysql, sql

I have checkbox in my post and I want to delete a database row when checkbox is not checked but when I press update button nothing happend and the row wasn't deleted.
here is my codes

```
if (isset($_POST['save-author-to-book'])) {
        $key = 'save-author-to-book';
        $values_to_save = array();
        $new_values = $_POST["save-author-to-book"];
        $existing_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, true ) ;



        if(!empty($new_values)){
            foreach($new_values as $new_value ){
            $values_to_save[] = $new_value ;


            }
         update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $values_to_save ); 
        }


    }
    else{

        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $meta_value=''); 
        // break;

    }
```

any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the value of meta **key** is inside the if clause and is not set for the else.

try

```
else {
        $key = 'save-author-to-book';
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $meta_value=''); 
        // break;

    }
```

Comment: Yeah it was... happens to all of us ;)